# Which creature type appears most frequently as enemies in the Storm King's Thunder adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, storm-kings-thunder, wizards-of-the-coast

I am going to be playing *Storm King's Thunder* as a Ranger (Revised) soon. We are starting the campaign at level 1 and playing the introduction adventure to the campaign. Of course I will be picking Giant as my Greater Favored Enemy. But what is the best choice for my regular favored enemy? By best I mean the type of enemy from the categories I am allowed to choose that appears most frequently.

Note that I have spoken to my DM and she is fine with me asking the question as she is also curious about the distribution of monsters, but she says she doesn't have time to go through the book and find out.

Should I choose humanoids, beasts, undead, fey, or monstrosities? Which of these appears the most as enemies in *Storm King's Thunder*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It really depends on how your DM runs the campaign and how your party decides to proceed.

It's not possible to give you an itemized breakdown because I am familiar with SKT as a player, not a DM, and your campaign experience will be unique. That said, as laid out by the book:

**Humanoids** appear very frequently because you will encounter them both in towns and while out adventuring.

**Beasts** also appear fairly regularly, but not as often as humans.

There are some **Monstrosities** as well. They are nowhere near as common as humanoids or beasts but, unit for unit, they tend to be more dangerous.

You're likely to encounter some **Undead** but this is highly variable and depends on your party's direction.

We had a trivial amount of **Fey** in our SKT campaign but I believe it was something the DM added in specifically for one of the character's backstory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about the underlying question has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88988/discussion-on-answer-by-rykara-which-creature-type-appears-most-frequently-as-en).